# Receiving broadcast from notification on Android Oreo

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, background-process, android-8.0-oreo

I have a custom button in a sticky notification.
I used to attach a `PendingIntent` to it for receiving button clicks:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.setAction("com.example.app.intent.action.BUTTON_CLICK");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2000, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
contentViewExpanded.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);
```

When i run this code on Oreo , i get `BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed` in logcat and don't receive button click.

I registered receiver with manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".BroadcastReceiver.NotificationActionReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.app.intent.action.BUTTON_CLICK"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I also tried registering receiver in my code:

```
NotificationActionReceiver mMyBroadcastReceiver = new NotificationActionReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.example.app.intent.action.BUTTON_CLICK");
mContext.registerReceiver(mMyBroadcastReceiver, filter);
```

This works but only when the app is visible to user.

Thanks for help

Comment: @UmarHussain I know it has been changed :D i already read the docs but with no lucks.

Comment: Ph okay I actually didn't implemented broadcast in oreo yet so don't know why this issue is coming

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Never use an implicit `Intent` when an explicit `Intent` will work.

Replace:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.setAction("com.example.app.intent.action.BUTTON_CLICK");
```

with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActionReceiver.class);
```

And remove the `<intent-filter>` from the `NotificationActionReceiver` `<receiver>` element.

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Actually i thought my intent is already explicit because it was targeting my own app.

Comment: @BehnamMabodi: An explicit `Intent` is one where the `Intent` knows a specific component that is the target. Typically, you make one via the constructor that takes the Java `Class` object (in this case, `NotificationActionReceiver.class`). An implicit `Intent` is one that lacks the component, and so Android relies on other things like action strings, to find the component for you.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this issue as well on `Android 8 - Oreo`, but given my library project requirements, I don't have the explicitly named `BroadcastReceiver` class implementation, that the end-client will declare in it's `AndroidManifest`.

**Solution:**

Specify the application package on the `Intent` using [setPackage(String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage(java.lang.String)).

**Example**:

```
// Application unique intent action String
final String receiverAction = getApplicationContext().getPackageName() 
                             + BaseLibraryReceiver.ACTION_SUFFIX;
// No need for Class definition in the constructor.
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
// Set the unique action.
intent.setAction(receiverAction);
// Set the application package name on the Intent, so only the application
// will have this Intent broadcasted, thus making it “explicit" and secure.
intent.setPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
...
```

From the Android [Broadcasts: Security considerations and best practices](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html#security_considerations_and_best_practices) docs.

> In Android 4.0 and higher, you can specify a package with
>   setPackage(String) when sending a broadcast. The system restricts the
>   broadcast to the set of apps that match the package.

Here’s an example of the `BroadcastReceiver` declared (or merged) in to the end-client application’s `AndroidManifest`:

```
 <receiver
        android:name=“com.subclassed.receiver.ReceiverExtendedFromLibrary"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="${applicationId}.action.MY_UNIQUE_ACTION"/>
        </intent-filter>

 </receiver>
```

Since my example revolves around a library project that broadcasts an `Intent`, I’ve decided to keep the `<intent-filter>` and `<action />` in the `<receiver>` declaration. Otherwise, there would be non-unique broadcast actions being fired, which *could* lead to potential issues where multiple applications receive the wrong broadcast. This is mostly a safety precaution. Of course you still need to check the action in the implementation of the `BroadcastReceiver`.

Hope someone finds this helpful!

Comment: EXCELLENT WORK!! I was literally trying to figure out how to do this with dynamic packages, and stumbled across your post. Works like a charm thanks!!